# Convert Doc or Docx into HTML in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi

How to convert doc or docx into HTML in Java. Using Apache POI, I was able to convert doc to html but unable to convert docx into html? Please show me sample code? This code work with doc but not docx.

```
        HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(stream);

        WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
        wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
        Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        out.close();

        String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
```

Comment: You can use docx4j for that, see the example: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtml.java

Comment: @user960567, I am also stuck with same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @jnrdn0011 search for Office Open XML

Comment: Thanks, finally I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why this shouldn't / can't work.

Please review the following:

- [How to extract plain text from a DOCX file using the new OOXML support in Apache POI 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492738/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-a-docx-file-using-the-new-ooxml-support-in-apache)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507019/751158

In short, make sure you're using an up-to-date version of POI, and have all of the required libraries.

(If you need additional assistance, please explain what isn't working.  Are you getting compile-time errors?  Run-time errors?  Unexpected output?)

Comment: Thanks. Your links simply shows how to extract docx but I need to convert docx into html.

Comment: @user960567 - How were you converting the *.doc into HTML?  Working with the *.docx really shouldn't be any different.  What have you tried, and where are you running into issues?