# Unable to convert docx to html using Java

Tags: html, apache-poi, document, docx

I need to convert .docx file content to HTML text in order to display in web ui.

I've used **Apache POI**'s **XWPFDocument** class but haven't been able to get any results yet; **getting empty string**. My code is based on [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9047044/282855).

Here's also my code:

```
public JSONObject uploadDocxFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
        XWPFDocument wordDocument = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);

        WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
        org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        serializer.transform(domSource, new StreamResult(stringWriter));
        out.close();

        String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
        String htmlText = result;

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("content", htmlText);
        jsonObject.put("success", true);
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a .docx to html using Apache POI and getting no text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103421/converting-a-docx-to-html-using-apache-poi-and-getting-no-text)

Comment: there's no proper answer at there.. owner of question opened that question with the same reason with me; but he added a comment that he has no problem while getting text.

Answer (score 1):

even if it's too late I think that the previous code can be modified in this way (it works with word97 document)

```
    private static void convertWordDoc2HTML(File file)
    throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException,TransformerException, IOException {       
    //change the type from XWPFDocument to HWPFDocument
    HWPFDocument hwpfDocument = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);          
             hwpfDocument = new HWPFDocument(fileSystem);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new   WordToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
    org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
    //add processDocument method 
    wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(hwpfDocument);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    out.close();

    String result = new String(out.toByteArray());

    String htmlText = result;
    System.out.println(htmlText);

    }
```

I hope it can be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to do this and it seems to be working. If you're using Maven you can just [add the dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.docx4j|docx4j|2.8.1|jar) (but use version 3.0.0) and then use one of the [docx4j sample programs](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples) called `ConvertOutHtml.java`. Just change the filepath in `ConvertOutHtml.java` to point to your file and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generating an empty html output because you are not processing any document in the converter.

Anyway, if it is a docx you should be using XHTMLConverter to convert it to HTML instead of WordToHtmlConverter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653911/2054610)